# Show Data missing from Server Explorer Context Menu - Can't View Data

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Up until today I could right click on a database table in visual studio 2012 server explorer and I would see an option to "Show Data" there was another option I cant recall the name of that opened the "Design Surface."

Those options are gone and now I can only refresh, copy, or click properties in the context menu. How do I get my context menu options back?

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you found out what the cause was?

Comment: @MattSull87 I have not. It was on my virtual machine so I could get around it when using a different machine. I did read that one person solved something similar by reinstalling visual studio. If you try that let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've re-installed VS but it didn't resolve the issue. More of a workaround than a solution is to use [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). When you run the program and use server object explorer (similar to server explorer) you can browse to the directory where your database is and from there you can view table data.